# Where to get jartoprc.exe?

Tags: palm-os, palm

Can anyone tellme where to get jartoprc.exe and jartoprc_w.exe for Java Web Sphere for Palm OS convertor to PRC??

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, ACCESS doesn't have the rights to distribute the IBM WebSphere Java tools anymore, so there's no public location where you can get the jar2prc tool for Palm OS Garnet.